# Extracting Capital Letters on a String during KeyPress

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I have two TextBoxes..

I want to extract/duplicate ALL CAPITAL LETTERS to be inputted by the user to another TextBox during an event of KeyPress.

Logic :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress()

'If the Character is a Capital Letter Then
'   Copy and Concatenate it to the second TextBox
'End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, TWO TextBoxes

Comment: (Side note, you can always edit your message if you did some mistakes... I did it for you this time)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
For i = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
    Dim c As Char = TextBox1.Text.Chars(i)
    If Char.IsUpper(c) Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(c)
    End If
Next
```

If you need it as a function:

```
Private Function ExtractUppers(ByVal txt As TextBox) As String
    Dim sExtract As String = ""
    For i = 0 To txt.Text.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = txt.Text.Chars(i)

        If Char.IsUpper(c) Then
            sExtract = sExtract & c
        End If
    Next

    Return sExtract
End Function
```

And in your button:

```
 TextBox2.Text = ExtractUppers(TextBox1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It was solved by my friend! :) Thanks for your replies!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChange()

      CapitalLetter = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[^A-Z]", String.Empty)
      TextBox2.Text = CapitalLetter

End Sub
```

Comment: I've change the event to TextChange()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this trick:

```
If letterVar = letterVar.ToUpper() then
    TextBox2.Text &= letterVar
End if
```